# Any useful Cloudwatch metrics for Kinesis Firehose (in addition to Kinesis Stream)?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am creating a dashboard of monitors/metrics of my team's service, which utilizes a Kinesis Stream and Kinesis Firehose to get our data from EDX to our S3 bucket.

I've identified a few useful Kinesis Stream metrics on Cloudwatch, particularly:

- IncomingRecords
- ReadProvisionedThroughputExceeded
- WriteProvisionedThroughputExceeded

With these metrics in place, are there any Firehose metrics that would add anything meaningful to my team's dashboard? I am looking through the metrics and can't find anything that I think adds much value, but I wanted to get others' thoughts to see if I'm potentially overlooking a useful monitor.